# template std::map as class member

Tags: c++, templates, stdmap

I need something like this as class member:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, template<class> T>> m_map;
```

error message: `template is not allowed`

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Thx

Comment: Could you describe what you want that to mean? It doesn't make sense as it is.

Comment: Did you just mean to give `T` as the second inner template argument?

Comment: Yep, what is this `template<class>` there :)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `template<class>` from the declaration of the map.

```
template<class T>
class A
{
   std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, T>> m_map;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::map<>` expects (concrete) type arguments, but `template<class> T` is not a type, it follows that `std::map<std::string, template<class> T>>` is not a type.

"Something like this" is not a good enough specification, unfortunately.

If you really mean *"map string to (map of string to T)"*, then the following would be a proper, reusable solution:

```
// Declare a template type "map of string to (map of string to T)"
template <typename T>
using foobar = std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, T>>;

....

foobar<int> frob;
```

See http://ideone.com/YZ6FRa .

As a member one time shot, this is possible, too:

```
template <typename T>
class Foobar {
    std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, T>> m_map;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to have `std::map` as a **class template parameter**, `std::map` actually takes four template arguments, two of which are defaulted.

```
#include <map>

template <template <typename, typename, typename, typename> class T>
void func()
{
}

int main()
{
    func<std::map>();
}
```

Then you can typedef it:

```
typedef T<std::string, int, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, int>>> my_map;
```

(Optionally `std::string` and `int` are template parameters you pass along to func.)